# Eric IDE, Qt File Dialog: show hidden files

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, eric-ide

How am I supposed to handle hidden files like `.gitignore` in my Eric project? Open Dialog does not seem to have an option to show hidden files; I couldn't find any such option anywhere in settings or configurations. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Qt File Dialog, you can right click on the file list. Show Hidden Files checkbox is on the context menu.